# Unable to start Active MQ on Linux

Tags: activemq-classic

I am trying to get ActiveMQ server running on a RaspberryPI Debian Squeeze box and all appears to be installed correctly but when I try and start the service I am getting the following...

root@raspberrypi:/var/www/activemq/apache-activemq-5.7.0# bin/activemq

INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'

INFO: Using java '/usr/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java'

/usr/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java: 1: /usr/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java:ELF0

```
                                                       4°: not found
```

/usr/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java: 2: /usr/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tasks provided by the sysv init script:

```
restart         - stop running instance (if there is one), start new instance

console         - start broker in foreground, useful for debugging purposes

status          - check if activemq process is running

setup           - create the specified configuration file for this init script

                  (see next usage section)
```

Configuration of this script:

```
The configuration of this script can be placed on /etc/default/activemq or /root/.activemqrc.

To use additional configurations for running multiple instances on the same operating system

rename or symlink script to a name matching to activemq-instance-<INSTANCENAME>.

This changes the configuration location to /etc/default/activemq-instance-<INSTANCENAME> and

$HOME/.activemqrc-instance-<INSTANCENAME>. Configuration files in /etc have higher precedence.
```

root@raspberrypi:/var/www/activemq/apache-activemq-5.7.0#

It looks like there is an error somewhere but I am a fairly newbie at this and don't know where to look.

Comment: Do you also get that error with `bin/activemq start` ?

Comment: Also since you are on the raspberry pi, it might be worthwhile to have a look at [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) as a lightweight alternative since probably ActiveMQ will consume too much memory for the pi.

Answer (score 23):

Just adding an answer since,becoz as per the documentation , the command is wrong

to start activemqm, use

Navigate to [installation directory/bin] and run `./activemq start` or simple `bin/activemq start`

if you want to see it live in a window use `bin/activemq console`

To stop, you have to kill the process

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was having this same issues as well since the documentation says to just do ./activemq, no start

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get it working and there was nothing in any logs. Running `bin/activemq console` showed me the error.

Answer (score 2):

The default ActiveMQ "getting started" link sends u here : http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html which is the "Getting Started Guide for ActiveMQ 4.x".

If you scroll down main documentation page, you will find this link with the proper commands :
http://activemq.apache.org/version-5-getting-started.html